# WPF change window height

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am using a WPF Window with contains a frame where I add the content of different pages I have.
The problem is that all of these pages have the same Width but different Height.

So what I would like to do is to be able to set the window's height, to the height of the page inside of the window's frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the window height, aside from looking horrible to the end user, comes with all sorts of complications. For example, what if your content has a greater height than the screen can display? Would your window go off the screen?

A better option may be to look into a control that gives a scroll bar if the content exceeds the window height.

Answer (score 0):

In `wpf` you can set window property

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

or

```
SizeToContent="Height"
```

As @Joeb454 already answered this may looks horrible during navigation (user-experience-wise).